# Text rendered with incorrect color on IE and Edge

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have [this test page](http://triplov.com/revistaTriplov/) that I am trying on several browsers. All them except those from Microsoft, render the page correctly regarding to the text color.

This is how this should be...

[image]

this is how IE and Edge render it

[image]

I did everything, cleaned the cache, but nothing makes this be rendered correctly on IE/Edge.

Any ideas?

Comment: Page renders "incorrectly" for me in Chrome as well. Not surprising as the body text color is set to `#333`.

Comment: in which line of the css are you seeing that?

Comment: Line 930 of http://triplov.com/revistaTriplov/wp-content/cache/wpfc-minified/6cd6b53d964b7bb3d8ad096fce0365b0/1506099144index.css

Comment: what? I am seeing this line on the server and it says `color:#aaa;" (??) I just opened the css file for edition now using terminal...

Comment: Whatever file you're viewing or editing, is not the one you're serving it seems.

Comment: damn, a wordpress cache plugin was serving a cached version. THANKS for pointing me on the right direction. Please convert your comments to that so I can accept it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page renders "incorrectly" for me in Chrome as well because the text-color for the `body` element is set to `#333` on line 930 of

http://triplov.com/revistaTriplov/wp-content/cache/wpfc-minified/6cd6b53d964b7bb3d8ad096fce0365b0/1506099144index.css

Probably you're not serving the file you think you're serving.

Comment: thanks. Wordpress cache plugin was serving the wrong file and I forgot about that.